# Better tutorial on Netbeans new language support plug-in?

Tags: javascript, plugins, netbeans, module, programming-languages

I am using a new javascript based server side language. It does something exactly similar to what PHP does—but uses javascript syntax to process server response and handle logic. Netbeans is my favorite editor, and I need to develop a new editor plug-in for Netbeans to provide syntax coloring and code assistance support for that language. It is suppose to behave like netbeans PHP editor; just replacing PHP code support with javascript code support.(It should support HTML syntax as well, just like the PHP editor does).

I will be much grateful, if you could provide me better tutorials on developing new language support plugins on Netbeans. What I found by googling didn't describe nicely what I looked for. If there is a way, that existing netbeans Javascript support and html support could merge together just in the way that PHP editor does, it would have been much easier. eg:

```
<%
var myPerson={"name":"test name","age":25};

function savePerson(person){
.... ${any logic}
}
savePerson(myPerson);
%>

<div><span>......</span></div>
```

If there is a way of instructing the existing Netbeans HTML editor to identify '<%' as ' <script > and '%>' as </script >, my requirement will probably be met.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/embedding_javascript_editor_in_java) describes doing something like what you want (JavaScript embedded in Java though, not HTML). The same approach should work in your case.